# Como fazer "data-binding" de duas variaveis no mesmo select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho este código que me está a fazer vm.service.type = serviceType.name :

```
   <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="field_type"><b>Type</b></label>
        <div class="input-icon right">
            <select required class="form-control"
                    id="field_type"
                    name="type"
                    ng-model="vm.service.type"
                    ng-options="serviceType.name as serviceType.name for serviceType in vm.servicetypes">
                <option></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="vm.service.type==null" class="form-group has-error">
            <p class="help-block" ng-show="vm.service.type==null" data-translate="entity.validation.required">
                This field is required.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como é que faço para que vm.service.serviceTypeId = serviceType.id...Isto sem adicionar outro campo ao formulário.

Nota: Estas variáveis já existem no controller e já tenho tudo o que é necessário para fazer o que pretendo.

Answer (score 0):

acho que só de você colocar no controller

```
vm.service.id  = vm.service.type ;
```

O JS vai fazer referência ao mesmo espaço de memória e qualquer alteração em `type` refletirá em `id`

Mas caso não funcione perfeitamente você pode também usar o ng-change assim:

```
<select required class="form-control"
    id="field_type"
    name="type"
    ng-model="vm.service.type"
    ng-change="vm.service.id = vm.service.type"
    ng-options="serviceType.name as serviceType.name for serviceType in vm.servicetypes">
        <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu simplificaria o campo `ng-options`, de forma a simplificar a sua leitura.

Quando temos um `array` composto por `objectos`, ao iterar sobre ele o `item` refere o objecto, então escolhi a propriedade `.name` para o texto das `<option>` e no `ng-change` declaro que o `vm.service.serviceTypeId` é igual à propriedade `.id` do `item`.

```
<select required class="form-control"
                id="field_type"
                name="type"
                ng-model="vm.service.type"
                ng-options="item.name for item in vm.servicetypes"
                ng-change="vm.service.serviceTypeId=item.id">
</select>
```